# How to retrieve class property types from a class type?

Tags: typescript, reflection

I have the following class:

```js
class Animal {
  name: string
  age: number
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve the types of the class's properties without it being initialized.
Here is how I expect to be using this:

```js
function getClassPropertyTypes(classType) {
  // perform some magic
}

// The returned value should be either an array or object with the property key and its type
getClassPropertyTypes(Animal)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect as return value, since types are not values.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin When I say type, I mean the value you get when you do a typeof, does that make it clearer?

Comment: If you want union of types of properties, then you can `type PropertyValues<T> = T[keyof T]`, then use it with the class like `PropertyValues<Animal>`, in this case it will be `string | number`, if this is not what you want, I'm not sure what is. You can't return types from functions, because types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: @AlexChashin Apparently, he wants the values `[ 'string' | 'number' ]` at runtime instead of the type `string | number` at compile time. I am not aware of any functionality within the compiler that would be able to generate different values based on the outcome of type inference. Moreover, a system that would map types to terms would collide with the explicit [non-goal #5 here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals): "[...] emit different code based on the results of the type system".